# Changing the css path wordpress localhost

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently creating a Wordpress theme.
I have a style.css but also a style.scss in a css/sass directory.
The wrodpress theme automatically links to the style.css but I want it to use the style.scss file. 
How can I force the theme to use the style.scss theme located in template/css/sass/style.scss?

I appreciate your help

Comment: Wordpress automatically links to theme/style.css. Do you have a link set up to link to the css file that is output from style.scss? That's what wordpress will need to read.

Comment: In my head.php I link to the style.scss file but WordPress ignores it

Comment: Yep, you need to link to the css file that is output when style.scss is compiled. Scss files have to be compiled before wordpress or any page for that matter can understand how to style the page.

Comment: Okay so the thing is I am loading a icon file which is in a fonts folder. I am doing that through @font-face but it's simply ignored in the css file